# Can I use polymer/web components in a native android app w/o Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, polymer

If I'm not mistaken, you need a web server to use/test Polymer's web components (such as the paper elements) on your computer due to browser permissions issues stemming from loading  local `file://`s.

(A simple solution is to navigate to the directory where the polymer files are you want to try and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` then load `http://localhost:8000` and all is good.)

But how about if I want to employ web components/Polymer elements in a native java android app inside a simple [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) w/o dealing with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or setting up a web server somehow inside my app.  Will I be able to do it easily, or will I have the same permissions issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes! I'm hoping to write an article on this in the next few weeks. For the imports to load from `file://`, I've been successful with the following settings:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable Javascript.
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); // Enable HTML Imports to access file://.
```

Note: this is also using the Chrome webview (Android 4.4.3+).

Comment: Ah hah!  That last method looks important :)  It was only added in Jellybean, so, chromium/webkit webview differences aside, probably anything older than JB is SOL on that basis alone. -- thanks!

Comment: Android apps dependent on the Chrome variation of WebView can bundle Chrome when targeting "anything older then JB", so maybe you aren't SOL.  (I haven't actually done it myself but have seen discussion of it.)  Whether that  will be compatible with the techniques required to incorporate polymer - I don't know.  Hopefully that will be covered by the article that @ebidel is writing!

Comment: Hi Eric,It would really be awesome if you would be able to write a small article that describes the limitations, from which WebView in android are WebComponents natively supported. I work at a company that needs a multy paltofrm solution and we are really interested in the Cordova + WebComponents approach. Reasons are endless.

Comment: Hi Eric. Could you please describe as well the build process with vulcanize and all the needed parameters to be able to pack the whole polymer web app to the phone app? I end up with failures w/o being able to get things running.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know if the same concept would work on iOS?