# Can i use Polymer in native iOS WebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, native, polymer

I need to use Polymer in my web based iOS app. The Cordova/Phonegap is the last solution. I readed this question: [Can I use polymer/web components in a native android app w/o Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708308/can-i-use-polymer-web-components-in-a-native-android-app-w-o-cordova) Can i do this in iOS?
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  I'm doing it, and my app is fully loading within three seconds.

Comment: Now my cordova project do same, 3 sec load. But i can not use polymer in standard UIWebView. Can i do something to get work with file:// requests?

Comment: You need <access origin="*"/> in your config.xml.  If that doesn't work, open a new question with some specifics on what's going wrong.  :)

Comment: This is my original question: Can i use Polymer in NATIVE UIWebView WITHOUT Cordova? :)

Comment: I haven't done that, but I don't know of any reasons why you wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @geppy , can you tell me the name of your app so I can download it? I'm trying to make a collection of iOS apps made w/ Polymer.

Comment: @Oneezy It's called "MOMO": https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/momo-stock-discovery/id939312137?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. Unless some material progress has been made on the platform, the instantiation period is not survivable. We were proceeding in a similar fashion, using UIWebView to embed Polymer-based components, but we ended up seeing about a 20-25 second delay while polymer instantiated — consistently replicable across devices. So, I'd answer "no" but your mileage may vary.

You can sample yourself by embedding the polymer-project.org site in a UIWebView/WKWebView component and see how they've solved for the delay in load. Smart, but even the most elegant static artifice will still suffer from the instantiation period.

For what it's worth - I thought Polymer was really all that and a can of corn. I await anxiously the day that they can go native with the platform across the major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't forget

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I spent hours trying to figure out why things weren't rendering properly on iOS... adding this to the top of your document makes magic happen.